# How can a ringtone be stored as a string?

Tags: android, uri, ringtone

In my application I need the user to select a ringtone as an application sound. I use `RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER` to get the selected ringtone. It returns the ringtone's `Uri`, and I can turn that into a ringtone and it all works just fine. But here's the tricky part:

All my application data is kept in an XML file, so I need a way to save the ringtone as a `String`.
I was thinking of just getting the ringtone's path using `Uri.getPath()` and saving the path in my app. But I can't find a way to convert the path back to a ringtone when I need to use it.
Here's the code I tried to convert a Uri to String and back:

```
String ringtonePath = ringtoneUri.getPath();
ringtoneUri = Uri.parse(ringtonePath);
Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getActivity(), ringtoneUri);
```

It doesn't work.
LogCat outputs:

```
Failed to open ringtone /internal/audio/media/13
```

and ringtone gets `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Uri.path` only returns the `path` part of the URL. For instance, if the URI is "http://hello.com/world/1", then `path` is only the "/world/1" part of the URI. You should store the result of `Uri.toString()` in your XML instead.